# How to efficiently create and write to multiple files in Java?

Tags: java, file

I want to fetch some data let's say **StudentActivityData** from **startDate** to **endDate**.

Since the data can be huge, the API to get the StudentActivity gives paginated results and I store the data intermittently in a Map with key as StudentId and value as StudentActivity for each paginated result.

Due to large size of data I want to create files corresponding to each student (filename as StudentId) and store the result in those files.

What is the efficient way to create and write data to files for the above mentioned scenario?

Note:

1) I cannot use database in the above scenario since I have to send the individual file as an attachment in the email as notification.

2) So we have a notification system which will eventually send an email. I am writing scheduling jobs in which first job will fetch the data and write to file and if the first job succeeds then the second job will pick all files and upload them to S3 and the generated link is sent to the notification client so that they may use it for attachment.

3) Individual files may not be large as I will be doing some filtering on the data.

Comment: Rather than using files, wouldn't large data be best stored in a database of some sort?

Comment: have you tried with Streams ? Or Collection.parallelStream()

Comment: Open the files and write to them? "Efficient" in what sense? What actual problem are you facing? What do you want the files to look like? Why use files at all?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I need to send the file as an attachment in the mail.

Comment: You want to send "huge data" in an email ? Strange but OK. You do not need actual files to create an email. In fact, you could even *probably* write a streaming email generator which reads data on the fly from your API and write them to SMTP. That seems efficient in almost any regard (though probably easier said than done, depending on the format of your mail).

Comment: @DaveNewton Efficient as in I don't want to iterate over the map and create/write to file. Writing to file is needed as I need to send it as an attachment over the email.

Comment: as @GPI pointed out, you don't need a physical file to send an attachment, if you handle the email sending in java.

Comment: @sarsjits Why store the in a map if you're just going to dump them to a file? Why write them to a file if you're just going to create an email? (Noting that if they're "huge" email likely isn't the best solution either--why not send a link to a file?)

Comment: @GPI So we have a notification system which will eventually send an email. I am writing scheduling jobs in which first job will fetch the data and write to file and if the first job succeeds then the second job will pick all files and upload them to S3 and the generated link is sent to the notification client so that they may use it for attachment.

Comment: @DaveNewton I updated the question with couple of Notes. An individual file may not be that large.

Comment: What do you use the map for, if later you don't want to iterate over it? Why don't you write to the target files directly?